# postGrowthRates is a list, I am deleting the 0th element to run a for loop and then adding it back to the list is there a better way to do this?

Tags: python, python-2.7

### Need help to improve the code

postGrowthRates is a list of numbers, I am deleting the 0th element to run a for loop and then adding  it back to the list is there a better way to do this?

```
Fs=[]                                                
Fye= savings*(1+0.01*postGrowthRates[0])-expenses      
Fs.append(Fye)                                 
y=  postGrowthRates[0]
del postGrowthRates[0]
j=1
for i in postGrowthRates:                     
    x=Fs[j-1]*(1+0.01*i)-expenses                 
    Fs+=[x,]                                 
    j+=1
postGrowthRates.insert(0,y)>
```

Comment: Don't bother deleting it. Just use `for i in postGrowthRates[1:]`. If you're worried about running out of memory, use `iterator = iter(postGrowthRates); next(iterator); for i in iterator:`

Comment: Thanks Sir, I have just started learn to coding , much appreciated, you have a good day :)